# MYSQL: How to count and group from 2 tables and then join to the 3rd table

Tags: mysql

Can someone help me, please?
I want to count all the occurrences of "username" field from 2 tables(comments_table & comment_replies) that are not more than a week old. After I get the result, I now want to get the "profile_image" of each username from the "users" table.

**comments_table looks like this**:
[image: comments_table]

Below is the comment_replies table

**comment_replies looks like this:**
[image: comment_replies]

I have already done 80% of the job by writing this query:

```
    SELECT username, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM (
    SELECT username FROM comments_table WHERE date_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
    UNION ALL
    SELECT username FROM comment_replies WHERE date_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
) table1 
GROUP BY username ORDER BY total DESC
```

And it runs perfectly well by giving this output:

[image: output]

Here is my problem: I want to join this result to the "users" table so that I can get the "profile_image" for each username. The "users" table has the username column as a unique column:

[image]

I know i can use the username column to join but I'm just stuck. Please help.
I have searched on Stock Overflow and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735911/mysql-join-count-rows-from-another-table) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641928/mysql-query-join-3-tables-together-group-by-one-column-and-count-for-the-othe) but they didn't address my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to join user table with your query:

```
SELECT u.username,u.profile_image,t.total
FROM `users` u
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT username, COUNT(*) AS total
  FROM (
    SELECT username FROM comments_table WHERE date_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
    UNION ALL
    SELECT username FROM comment_replies WHERE date_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
  ) table1 
  GROUP BY username) t
ON u.username=t.username
ORDER BY t.total;
```

I corrected the spelling of keyword INNER.